# Trigger: Error de sintaxis

Tags: postgresql, trigger, sintaxis

Quería crear un trigger después de cada actualización en una tabla, pero me daba error de sintaxis. La cosa es que me da ese error incluso reduciendo la sentencia a lo más simple, a un select. El trigger se llama "test", la tabla "prueba" y el esquema es "public":

```
CREATE TRIGGER public.test
ON prueba
AFTER UPDATE
AS
select * from public.prueba;
```

Lo que me llama más la atención es que el error lo seeñala al principio de la sentencia:

> ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «.» LINE 1: CREATE TRIGGER
> public.test

Comment: Si le quito el esquema en CREATE TRIGGER, el error me lo señala en ON:

CREATE TRIGGER test ON public.prueba AFTER UPDATE AS select * from public.prueba;

ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «ON» LINE 2: ON public.prueba

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Depende del motor de BD que este usando, ¿cuál es? lo que te puedo decir es que un select en un trigger no tiene sentido y algún motor hasta puede permitir hacerlo de esta forma.

Comment: Hola Patricio. Estoy con pgadmin4 5.0
El select era por reducir al mínimo la acción a dispararse. Mi intención es sacar un csv con unos determinados campos tras cada actualización de una tabla.

Comment: Es que en un trigger simplemente no puede haber un select que retorne datos al usuario,  verifica la documentación: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html dice: "you cannot create SELECT triggers. "

Comment: O sea mi comentario sería la repuesta de tu pregunta, el tema es que en realidad tu pregunta es otra : "sacar un csv con unos determinados campos tras cada actualización de una tabla", yo te diría plantea por ese lado tu pregunta, es un problema interesante, no sé igual si se puede implementar algo así pero esta bueno que lo preguntes.

Comment: Gracias Patricio. he visto algunos hilos al respecto, pero no lo consigo. A ver si al final acaba saliendo!

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis para crear un disparador como el que quieres es

```
CREATE TRIGGER nombre_disparador
AFTER UPDATE ON tabla
EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcion_disparador()
```

y `funcion_disparador` debe estar definida con tipo de retorno `TRIGGER`, algo del estilo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcion_disparador()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        [código PLPGSQL]
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

La función `funcion_disparador` tiene definidas las variables `NEW`, que se refiere al registro que se actualizará y `OLD` que se refiere al registro previo. Esto te permite hacer modificaciones a la información que será actualizada (en la forma `NEW.campo := valor`).